# How to set fixed content on a fixed background?

Tags: html, css

I been wondering for a long time now how you can fix a text content on a fixed background.

This is my code to explain it:

**CSS**

```
.background {
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 400px; 
}
.fixed-content {
    position: fixed; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="fixed-content">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the second `div`'s class has a typo in it. Is it the same in your code, or you simply did the mistake while writing your question?

Comment: I wrote it wrong when i published here.

Comment: What do you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/e83rL09s/1/

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you want.